# Windows + RoR: Gem installs, run rake gems:install, can't find gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, bundler

```
$> gem install multi_json
<Lots of invalid gemspec warnings>
Successfully installed multi_json-1.0.3
.
.
.
$> bundle exec rake gems:install
<Lots of invalid gemspec warnings>
    ERROR: Error installing searchlogic:
           activesupport requires multi_json (~> 1.0)
```

Using Windows XP
Ruby 1.8.7
Rails 2.3.8
Gem 1.8.10

GemFile:

```
# app
#gem "mysql", "2.7"
gem "sqlite3"
gem "lockfile"
gem "ssl_requirement", "0.1.0"
gem "attr_encrypted", "1.1.2"
# gem "searchlogic", "2.4.28", :require => nil
gem "will_paginate", "2.3.14", :require => nil
gem "paperclip"


gem "garb", "0.7.6"
gem "delayed_job", "2.0.3"
gem "httparty", "0.5.2"


gem "pony", "1.1"
gem "friendly_id", "3.0.6"
gem "stringex", "1.1.0"
gem "i18n", "0.4.2"

gem "sms_fu", "1.1.1"

# gems needed for windows
gem "spruz", "0.2.13", :git => "git://github.com/flori/spruz.git"
gem "json_pure", "~> 1.5.4"
```

in environment.rb

```
 require "bundler/setup"
  Bundler.require(:default)
  require "will_paginate"
  config.gem "searchlogic", :version => "2.4.28"
```

I've already ran bundle install. It says my bundle is complete!... but it lies... so hard coroe.

Answer (score 0):

try to install the gems with

```
bundle install
```

instead of

```
bundle exec rake gems:install
```

Comment: Does that work in a Rails 2.3.8 environment? I have switched long time ago, so I don't know any more ...

Comment: that's what I did initially. it says my bundle is complete.